# "Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : x' and 'y' lengths differ" for SVM

Tags: r, plot, svm

Getting the following error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

When I try to run the following code. I understand that it has to do with the lengths of my x and y.:

```
install.packages("e1071")
library("e1071")

mydata <- read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv", sep=";", header=TRUE);

#Go on split the data into a training and test set.

index <- 1:nrow(mydata)
testindex <- sample(index, trunc(length(index)/3))
testset( <-mydata[testindex,]
trainset <- mydata[-testindex,]

svm.model <- svm(formula = as.factor(quality) ~ residual.sugar, data = trainset, kernel = linear, method = "class")
svm.pred <- predict(svm.model, trainset, type = "class")

table(pred = svm.pred, true = trainset[,10)

plot(svm.pred, testset)
```

I checked the lengths, and I'm not understanding why my test set is coming up with 12.

Thanks

Comment: `testset( <-mydata[testindex,]` there is a parenthesis after `testset`

Comment: lol my mistake in putting that in, but that has nothing to do with the original problem. The error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

`svm.pred` is a varaible concerning predictions made on the training set:

```
svm.pred <- predict(svm.model, trainset, type = "class")
```

Then you want to plot actual vs predicted, but you erroneously take the actual values of the test set and the predicted ones of the training set (`svm.pred`):

```
plot(svm.pred, testset)
```

That's why the x,y lengths differ.

If you want to validate on the test set, you should make predictions on the test set, so your `svm.pred` should be:

```
svm.pred <- predict(svm.model, testset, type = "class")
```